# react-native-html-to-pdf file is not stored in given directory in iOS

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have used react-native-html-to-pdf to convert html to pdf. In iOS, the file is not found in the Documents folder even though it is mentioned in the options. Printing the filepath in log shows a different filepath which I could not find in the iphone.

```
let options = {
          html:  content,
          fileName: 'Test',
          directory: 'Documents',
        };
        try {
          let file = await RNHTMLtoPDF.convert(options);
          console.log('file.filePath');
          console.log(file.filePath);
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e);
        }
```

log printed is /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/70CDEB26-7471-47A3-A6DE-328D323AC841/tmp/Test.pdf

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

If [this is the module](https://github.com/christopherdro/react-native-html-to-pdf) you are using, they clearly say

> Directory where the file will be created (`Documents` folder in example
> above). Please note, on iOS `Documents` is the only custom value that is
> accepted.

`Documents`, not `Download`.

Comment: I tried it too. Sorry it is a typo in the snippet.